# Plot multiple lines on x-axis Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am required to draw a chart showing changes on number of users (Increase or decrease) on behalf of changes employee made on campaigns, for this i am maintaining change log of employee activity. so i need to plot x-axis lines on every x-axis series.

I searched and yet not found any appropriate answer. this [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotlines-events/)  has only one line plotted on x-axis, but i need lines on every x-axis series.

one possible outcome could be, but will need to generate plotlines object for every line i need.

```
plotLines: [{
        color: '#FF0000',
        width: 2,
        value: 4.5
    }, {
        color: '#00FF00',
        width: 2,
        value: 5.5
    }]
```

Comment: Not clear what your desired outcome is, or which part of it is your actual question. However, yes, you will create an object for each `plotLine` that you need, as you've demonstrated in your code. So, what part do you still need help with?  Provide a fiddle of your actual use-case, with the specific issue that you need solved for best results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to generate the plotlines array yourself with the value matching the x-values of your data. Since you are using day increments, use the same for the plot lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/8mn674ch/1/

```
var data = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4];
var plotlines = [];
//var startTime = Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1).getTime();
var startTime = new Date(Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1)).getTime();
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var timeincr = startTime + 1000*3600*24*i;
  console.log(new Date(timeincr));
    var pline = { // mark the weekend
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            value: timeincr,
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    $report.html('click');
                },
                mouseover: function () {
                    $report.html('mouseover');
                },
                mouseout: function () {
                    $report.html('mouseout');
                }
            }
        };
    plotlines.push(pline);
}
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        plotLines: plotlines,
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        // one day
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andres, how can i add tooltip to plotted line.

Comment: Plot lines do not have the tooltip. You can have another series - a scatter - with lineWidth > 0 - you can set its data in the way that the series will be displayed as a vertical line just as a plotline. Then your series will look like plotlines but with the tooltip functionality. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.lineWidth

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but you can draw lines on every x-axis series with by changing the tickmarkPlacement:

```
xAxis: {
        tickWidth: 1,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        gridLineWidth: 1
    }
```